# Что означают квадратные скобки в распределённом условном типе?

Tags: typescript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означают квадратные скобки вокруг Type и any? Это кортеж из одного элемента, или что-то другое?

```
type ToArrayNonDist<Type> = [Type] extends [any] ? Type[] : never;
```

Comment: Да, это кортеж из одного элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Type]` - это значит массив из одного элемента типа `Type`, а `Type[]` - означает массив из неограниченного количества элементов типа `Type`

Comment: Первое в документации называют [Tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types). В русском переводе часто используют слово «[кортеж](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))»

Comment: @AlexeyTen Мне очень не привычно так называть массивы, только потому что у них фиксированная длина)))